# Get distinct values from MySQL JSON array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, distinct, concatenation

I got a MySQL data Table, with a JSON Column containing a list of Values:

CONSTRAINT_TABLE

```
 ID | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | CONSTRAINT_VALUES
----+-----------------+--------------------------------
 '2'| 'testtype'      |'[801, 751, 603, 753, 803]'
 ...| ...             | ...
```

What I want to have is a distinct, comma-seperated List of JSON-Values. I tried it with group_concat, but it applys to the arrays, not the single values.

```
SELECT group_concat(distinct constraint_values->>'$') 
FROM constraint_table c 
WHERE c.constraint_type = "testtype";
```

Actual result:

```
[801, 751, 603, 753, 803],[801, 751],[578, 66, 15],...
```

My target result:

```
801, 751, 603, 753, 803, 578, 66, 15 ...
```

without duplicates. As rows would be nice, too.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: moral of the story: it's always a bad idea to store comma seperated data in a column

Comment: For that you have to first normalize your data. Do you have a table containing constraint values normalized?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for necromancing, but I've encountered similar issue. The solution is: `JSON_TABLE()` available since MySQL 8.0.

First, merge the arrays in rows into one-row single array.

```sql
select concat('[',         -- start wrapping single array with opening bracket
    replace(
        replace(
            group_concat(vals),  -- group_concat arrays from rows
            ']', ''),            -- remove their opening brackets
        '[', ''),              -- remove their closing brackets
    ']') as json             -- finish wraping single array with closing bracket
from (
  select '[801, 751, 603, 753, 803]' as vals
  union select '[801, 751]'
  union select '[578, 66, 15]'
) as jsons;

# gives: [801, 751, 603, 753, 803, 801, 751, 578, 66, 15]
```

Second, use `json_table` to convert the array into rows.

```sql
select val
from (
    select concat('[',
        replace(
            replace(
                group_concat(vals),
                ']', ''),
            '[', ''),
        ']') as json
    from (
      select '[801, 751, 603, 753, 803]' as vals
      union select '[801, 751]'
      union select '[578, 66, 15]'
    ) as jsons
) as merged
join json_table(
    merged.json,
    '$[*]' columns (val int path '$')
) as jt
group by val;

# gives...
801
751
603
753
803
578
66
15
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table

Notice `group by val` for getting distinct values. You can also `order` them and everything...

Or you can use `group_concat(distinct val)` without the `group by` directive (!) to get one-line result.

Or even `cast(concat('[', group_concat(distinct val), ']') as json)` to get a proper json array: `[15, 66, 578, 603, 751, 753, 801, 803]`.

---

Read my [Best Practices for using MySQL as JSON storage](https://medium.com/@deltazero/mysql-as-smart-json-storage-200e6758f37e) :)