# Mysql - How can I merge two json arrays of strings without duplicates?

Tags: mysql

If I have two json arrays of strings in mysql, is there a native(or not native) way to merge these two arrays into one with unique strings?
If I try `json_merge` I get the following result with duplicates:

```sql
set @array1 =JSON_EXTRACT('["apple","pear","banana"]', '$');
set @array2 =JSON_EXTRACT('["pear","banana","apple","kiwi"]', '$');
select json_merge(@array1,@array2);
    > ["apple", "pear", "banana", "pear", "banana", "apple", "kiwi"]
```

And If is try `json_merge_preserve` gives me the same result:

```sql
set @array1 =JSON_EXTRACT('["apple","pear","banana"]', '$');
set @array2 =JSON_EXTRACT('["pear","banana","apple","kiwi"]', '$');
select json_merge_preserve(@array1,@array2);
    > ["apple", "pear", "banana", "pear", "banana", "apple", "kiwi"]
```

Is there a function that will return the unique array?

```
["apple",  "banana", "pear", "kiwi"]
```

Edit: `json_merge_patch` doesn't work because it only replaces the first array with the second:

```sql
set @array1 =JSON_EXTRACT('["apple","grape","banana"]', '$');
set @array2 =JSON_EXTRACT('["pear","banana","apple","kiwi"]', '$');
select json_merge_patch(@array1,@array2);
 > ["pear", "banana", "apple", "kiwi"]
```

In this case I lose `"grape"`. I believe that the logic in patch is `0 : 'val', 1:'val2'` merge with `0:val3` then `0 : 'val3', 1:'val2'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question still lives, here's a simple solution using MySQL 8.0's `JSON_TABLE`.

```
set @a1 ='["apple","grape","banana","banana","pear"]';
set @a2 ='["pear","banana","apple","kiwi","banana","apple"]';

select fruit
from json_table(
  json_merge_preserve(@a1, @a2),
  '$[*]' columns (
    fruit varchar(255) path '$'
  )
) as fruits
group by fruit; # get distinct values

# gives
apple
grape
banana
pear
kiwi
```

To get a one-line response, we have to drop `group by` and get a bit more creative.

Unfortunately, `JSON_ARRAYAGG` doesn't support `distinct` directive, so we'll have to use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```sql
select group_concat(distinct fruit)
from json_table(
  json_merge_preserve(@a1, @a2),
  '$[*]' columns (
    fruit varchar(255) path '$'
  )
) as fruits;
# without group by directive!

# gives: apple,banana,grape,kiwi,peas
```

To get a proper json array on-line response, we just play around with `CONCATs`:

```sql
select cast(
  concat('["', group_concat(distinct fruit separator '", "'), '"]')
  as json)
...

# gives: ["apple", "banana", "grape", "kiwi", "pear"]
```

---

**EDIT:**

I've found out a proper `JSON_ARRAYAGG` solution using one more nested virtual table to `group` results in.

```
select json_arrayagg(fruit)
from (
  select fruit
  from json_table(
    json_merge_preserve(@a1, @a2),
    '$[*]' columns (
      fruit varchar(255) path '$'
    )
  ) as fruits
  group by fruit -- group here!
) as unique_fruits;
```

---

Read my [Best Practices for using MySQL as JSON storage](https://medium.com/@deltazero/mysql-as-smart-json-storage-200e6758f37e) :)

Answer (score 1):

After too much thinking, and thanks to @lefred. I found a hack that can accomplish this. 
This is way too hacky, but i will publish it while someone else comes with a better implementation or the mysql guys make a proper function for this.

First, we replace the string strategically to create a json object instead of an array. 
Then, we use `json_merge_path` and finally we use `json_keys` to obtain an array :V

```sql
set @array1 ='["apple","grape","banana","banana","pear"]';
set @array2 ='["pear","banana","apple","kiwi","banana","apple"]';

set @aux1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@array1, ',', ' : "1", '), ']', ' : "1" }'), '[', '{');
set @aux2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@array2, ',', ' : "1", '), ']', ' : "1" }'), '[', '{');
select @aux1, @aux2;
select json_keys(json_merge_patch(json_extract(@aux1, '$'),json_extract(@aux2,'$')))

> ["kiwi", "pear", "apple", "grape", "banana"]
```

Comment: This works, but it's rather ugly. Please, see my answer based on JSON_TABLE.

Answer (score 1):

Use SELECT DISTINCT:

```
set @array1 =JSON_EXTRACT('["apple","grape","banana"]', '$');
set @array2 =JSON_EXTRACT('["pear","banana","apple","kiwi"]', '$');

select json_arrayagg(fruit) from (
    select 
        distinct fruit 
    from json_table(
        json_merge_preserve(@array1, @array2), 
        '$[*]' columns (fruit varchar(255) path '$')
    ) fruits
) f;
```

Comment: Yeah, the distinct would work as well. you are missing the `json_arrayagg` to return the json array, like this: `select json_arrayagg(fruit)
from (select 
    distinct fruit 
from json_table(
    json_merge_preserve(@array1, @array2), 
    '$[*]' columns (fruit varchar(255) path '$')
) fruits) f;`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, json_merge_preserve preserves duplicates. Also, if you are using MySQL 8.0.3 or over, json_merge is deprecated and json_merge_preserve should be used. I think that you need to use JSON_MERGE_PATCH.

More details here https://database.guide/json_merge_preserve-merge-multiple-json-documents-in-mysql/

Comment: No, that only replaces the first array with the second

Comment: Yeah, I see that now... did you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508478/get-distinct-values-from-mysql-json-array ? The question does not have an answer, but the question itself might help you.

Comment: So, are you suggesting is a bad idea to store json string arrays in MySQL?

Comment: Is there a specific need for storing data that way? It is usually hard to deal with data that has been stored this way. And in my experience, data stored like that is not intended to be used in operations or filters.

Comment: XDevApi now supports collections. The fact MySQL supports that, ask for tools to manage json in more robust way.