# MySQL merge json field with new data while removing duplicates, where the json values are simple scalar values

Tags: mysql, json

Suppose that I have a MySQL table with a JSON field that contains only numbers, like this (note: using MySQL 8):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id int,
    some_field json
);
```

Sample data:

id: 1
some_field: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

id: 2
some_field: [3, 6, 7]

id: 3
some_field: null

I would like to merge another array of data with the existing values of some_field, while removing duplicates. I was hoping that this might work, but it didn't:

```
update my_table set some_field = JSON_MERGE([1, 2, 3], some_field)
```

The result of this would be:

id: 1
some_field: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

id: 2
some_field: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]

id: 3
some_field: [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Possible duplicate, if you want a MySQL solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529216/mysql-how-can-i-merge-two-json-arrays-of-strings-without-duplicates

Comment: Otherwise consider fetching the array into a client application, merging whatever values you want, then UPDATE the row in the database with the modified array.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have 3 records in your table and you want to merge 1 and 2 as mentioned in your example.

I hope JavaScript is suitable to follow through for you.

```
// Get both the records

const records = db.execute(“SELECT id, some_field FROM my_table WHERE id=1 OR id=2”);

// You get both the rows.
// Merging row1, you can either use the Set data structure if you’re dealing with numbers like your example, or you could loop using a map and use the spread operator if using JSON. Since your object is an array, I’ll just be explaining to merge 2 arrays.

records[0].some_field = Array.from(new Set(records[0].some_field + record[1].some_field))

// Same for second record.

records[1].some_field = Array.from(new Set(records[0].some_field + record[1].some_field))

// Now update both the records in the database one by one.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I have thousands of records that require updating, this proposed solution starts to really degrade performance-wise.